# React Router v4 - Pre-Mount Component Without Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that takes a while to load. Actually, it's a component which loads an `<iframe>` of another website, which takes a while to load.

I would like the component to mount and therefore run the componentDidMount code block that loads the iframe so that when the user clicks on the 'create' tab, the user instantly sees the iframe in the correct the `<main>` section of the page.

Is there a way to instruct react-router to **pre-load the component** while retaining the same conditional rendering logic on route change and retaining the position on the page of the rendered component?

This is currently my `render()` statement on the root level of the app to give you some context:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav />
      <Snackbar
        open={this.props.snackbar.get().open}
        message={this.props.snackbar.get().message}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        onRequestClose={() => this.handleSnackbarRequestClose()}
      />
      <TreeViewer />
      <PayloadListener/>
      <main>
        <ThankYouModal open={this.props.showConfirmationModal.get()} handleClose={ () => this.props.showConfirmationModal.set(false) }/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/imageservices" component={ImageServicesController} />
          <Route path="/create"        component={Iframe} />
          <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
          <Route exact path="/analytics" component={AnalyticsController} />
          <Route path="/support"       component={SupportView} />
          <Route path='/login'         render={ (props) => <Login { ...props } /> } />
          <Route path='/logout'        render={ (props) => <Logout { ...props } /> } />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the component I would like React Router to pre-load:

`<Route path="/create" component={Iframe} />`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want it to appear "instantly", and if you can get to the create path from anywhere on your site, you'd pretty much have to load the iframe in the root of your website and toggle it's visibility with logic that looks at the window's location. Otherwise I'm not sure how you'd get around the actual downloading of the iframe's content without user experience delays.

Comment: hmm yeah just load it on the root level of the `<app />` and then use like local state to toggle visibility? I was thinking about that but wanted to see if there was a solution in react-router's domain first. @MichaelLyons

Comment: Adding `<iframe>` in the top of your page will cause it to load first, before the rest of your page is processed, unless you inject it dynamically. Please use `preload` as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not via react-router, but you can use `link` `preload` `as` `document` in your `index.html` to ensure the document is lazy-loaded by the browser. It's intended purpose is to preload documents which can then be displayed in iframe. You also won't need to change your router mechanism.

Read more about this here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content.

Basically, just add this to the `head` of your `index.html`:

`<link rel='preload' href='your_iframe_url' as='document'>`

Comment: I know the original question is asking about preloading an iframe, but is there a way like you mentioned to preload a normal html page?

Comment: The exact same way as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Well if you take a look at a [React component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting) you can see that **render** always runs before **componentDidMount**. So effectively you wouldn't be able to mount a component without rendering it.

These are the lifecycle methods called while mounting:

- `constructor()`
- `static getDerivedStateFromProps()`
- `render()`
- `componentDidMount()`

You can try a few things:

- Render the iframe when you need it and fade it in when it is loaded.

You can easily add an eventListener for the **load** event of the iframe and make the appropriate changes for it to fadeIn when the state changes.

```
...
componentDidMount() {
  this.iframe.addEventListener("load", this.handleLoad);
}

componentWillUnmout() {
  this.iframe.removeEventListener("load", this.handleLoad);
}
...
<iframe ref={ref => this.iframe = ref } />
...
```

> I've done this when I didn't always need the iframe. It was something sporadic and it was an always one page kinda thing.

- You can play around with the **[preload](https://w3c.github.io/preload/#x2.link-type-preload)** attribute

> This is ideal if you know the user will stumble upon the iframe content. You can start preloading content that the user will most likely encounter effectively preventing the user from waiting.

You can add this to the head of your document:

```
<link rel="preload" href="your-doc-url" as="document" />
```

And then use your iframe normally:

```
<iframe src="your-doc-url"></iframe>
```

If your iframe url is dynamic and dependent on some info from the authenticated user and you can't put it right away in your html file remember you can always use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to render it to the head tag whenever you have the info you want.